# urlrewriting in asp.net button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

Hi all I have seen many articles on `url rewriting` but I didn't find any as per my requirement. Assume I have two pages `Default.aspx` and `Default1.aspx`.. On initial load I would like to re write my `Default.aspx` to some thing like `urlrewrite\dummy.aspx` and on my `Default.aspx` I will have a button when I click on this I am going to redirect to `Default1.aspx` I would like to rewrite this to `urlrewrite\dummy1.aspx`

I just post the sample rewrites but if there is any better way of redirecting can you please help me..

Also what is the best way to rewrite all pages if I have some `20-50` pages

my global.asax file

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>
<script RunAt="server">

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes);
    }
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routeCollection)
    {
        string root = Server.MapPath("~");
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo info = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(root);
        System.IO.FileInfo[] files = info.GetFiles("*.aspx", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in files)
        {
            string pageName = fi.FullName.Replace(root, "~/").Replace("\\", "/");
            routeCollection.MapPageRoute(fi.Name + "Route", fi.Name, pageName);
        }

        routeCollection.MapPageRoute("DummyRouteName1", "Dummy", "~/Default2.aspx");
    }

    void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //  Code that runs on application shutdown

    }

    void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs

    }

    void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs when a new session is started

    }

    void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs when a session ends. 
        // Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode
        // is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set to StateServer 
        // or SQLServer, the event is not raised.

    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add routes in your Global.asax file on application start:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes);
}

private void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("DummyRouteName", "Dummy", "~/Default.aspx");
    ....
}
```

Usage:

```
Response.Redirect("~/Dummy");
```

In url you will see: *(server)/Dummy*

**Edit:**

here is how to automatically add routes:

```
// Get root directory
string root = Server.MapPath("~");
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(root);
// Get all aspx files
FileInfo[] files = info.GetFiles("*.aspx", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (FileInfo fi in files)
{
    // Get relative path
    string pageName = fi.FullName.Replace(root, "~/").Replace("\\", "/");
    // Add route
    routes.MapPageRoute(fi.Name + "Route", fi.Name.Replace(".aspx", ""), pageName);
}
```

Comment: Will this work in a web application as I am not developing my application in  `MVC`

Comment: Getting this error `Error 1 'System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection' does not contain a definition for 'MapPageRoute' and no extension method 'MapPageRoute' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: What's your project's .net framework version? It should be 4.0. [RouteCollection.MapPageRoute Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784594.aspx). Yes it works for web forms.

Comment: Ok thanks but as per I said if I have some `n` pages what's the way to rewrite shall I write all pages in that page or any Idea

Comment: Also my `Default` Page should also get rewrite

Comment: Small help as I am getting a plain `global.asax` file with out separate code file how can i add reference for `Server.Mappath`

Comment: Use **System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11151/discussion-between-vivekh-and-vano-maisuradze)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you got that rewriting part covered and only problem is postback, you can set postback to "friendly" URL by seting form action, like this :

```
Page.Form.Action = Page.Request.RawUrl;
```